# SP2010 Reporting Services 401 unauthorized for one web app but working for the others

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I have deployed Reporting Services to my farm.  From the application server, reporting services are working for all web apps.  However, via my WFEs, I have one web app which reports 401 Unauthorized, the other web apps on same WFE have reporting services working just fine.

I am at a loss.

```
Exception encountered for SOAP method GetSystemProperties: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.     at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()     at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the Report Server Integration site collection feature on site collections in that web app?

Is this SSRS SQL Server 2012? Have you associated the Service Application with that Web Application?